# Linux Mint 17.3 and Ubuntu 15.10 Both freeze after USB live boot

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, acpi

After booting into live USB after several seconds everything freezes I can't even open the terminal (CTR+ALT+F1),
Looked for a solution and found out that putting **acpi=off** on the boot menu should make it work,
It actually helped and I was able to use the live USB and install but the problem is that now I have to boot again using **acpi=off** in grub and it make the OS work only with one CPU thread, it doesn't recognizes my multi threaded CPU.

I use HP Laptop with i7 quadcore CPU and Quadro GPU (ZBook 15 G2)

What should I do?